# Как подписать компонент на извменения в store?

Tags: reactjs, flux

Есть 2 компонента-список и дейт пикер. Они связаны с двумя сторами. Первый стор  возвращает объекты ля заполнения списка, второй стор принимает дату и сетит внутри себя объект, значением которого является эта дата. Нужно сделать следующее. Выставили дату, в сторе обновился объект -> компонент-списка обновляется(то есть повторно срабатывает getItems). Из того, что видел в сети я понял,что надо каким-то образом подписать компонент списка на изменения стора дейтпикера. Например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308899/reactjs-flux-detect-store-data-change-between-components-not-parent-and-child) похожий вопрос, но я не совсем понимаю эту конструкцию(как ее использовать и где прописывать):

```
CommonStore.addChangeListener(render);
```

Как я понял эта строка подписывает компонент на изменения стора,но тут она прописана в index.js. У меня же нужные компоненты находятся  в других файлах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать

Comment: Если у вас flux - то вам нужно сторой выкидывать события изменения, а компоненты должны слушать эти события.
Грубо говоря как onClick на кнопке, при нажатии на кнопку - она запускает событие "onClick", а вы где то можете повесить слушателя этого события, например jQuery('button').click(fn....)
Вообще советую использовать redux или mobx

Comment: вот у меня 2 компонента. в одном кнопка,при ее нажатии встор копонента сетятся данные. в тоже время после нажатия мне надо обновить другой компонент,который подключен к другому стору.где прпоисать метод-слушатель?

Comment: В компоненте, которому нужно обновиться